# Cloudinary widget use in React

Tags: reactjs, cloudinary

I am new to React.  I am looking for a good way to upload photos to Cloudinary.  I saw the Cloudinary widget but I am having trouble implementing it in a React app as described:
https://cloudinary.com/blog/how_to_build_an_image_library_with_react_cloudinary#uploading_images

I put the script tag in index.html body:

```
<script src="//widget.cloudinary.com/global/all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

then try to use in component:

```
class Landing extends Component {
  uploadWidget() {
    cloudinary.openUploadWidget(
      { cloud_name: 'minetoo', upload_preset: 'mine', tags: ['xmas'] },
      function(error, result) {
        console.log(result);
      }
    );
  }
...
```

but I get the error:
'cloudinary' is not defined

My app's boilerplate is generated with create-react-app if that matters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is very normal as pointed [here](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2203) and [here](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#using-global-variables). You need to access the `cloudinary` object from the `window` object:

```
window.cloudinary.openUploadWidget(...)
```

Comment: thanks Chris, saved me from a headache debugging this

Answer (score -1):

You can use [React Cloudinary Uploader](https://github.com/app-masters/react-cloudinary-uploader) for Rect, it's the best solution at this time handle Cloudinary in React.